# how bash shell script construct array element with space

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, whitespace

I want to construct array element with `space`, it works while run in command line:

```
pc:/tmp$ b=('1 2' '3 4')
pc:/tmp$ echo $b
1 2
pc:/tmp$ echo ${b[1]}
3 4
```

But it get the elements split with `space` in script:

```
pc:/tmp$ cat t.sh
a="'1 2' '3 4'"
echo $a
b=($a)
echo $b
echo ${b[1]}
echo ${b[2]}

pc:/tmp$ bash t.sh
'1 2' '3 4'
'1
2'
'3
```

I want to get `'1 2'` with `echo $b` as get `'3 4'` with `${b[1]}` in script.

How could I achieve this?

And why it can't not works in script but works in command line?

Comment: `b=($a)`  splits the string on white space. You would have to write a parser for your `a`  to tear it apart.

Comment: If you tested `b=($a)` at the command line it would behave just the same way as it did in your script. This isn't a script-vs-command-line difference.

Comment: BTW, among the answers on the duplicates, I strongly suggest finding one that uses either the Python `shlex` module (if you want the closest possible accuracy to a real POSIX sh parser), or `xargs printf '%s\0'` (if you want something that's available everywhere and doesn't add more bugs than the minimum set `xargs` forces).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy THX, thanks for your time, maybe I should improve my search skill, that all relevant questions are helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code `a="'1 2' '3 4'"` does not create an array, it creates a string with embedded single-quotes.

```
$: a="'1 2' '3 4'"
$: echo "[$a]"
['1 2' '3 4']
```

If you want to create an array, you have to use the right syntax.

```
$: a=( '1 2' '3 4' )
$: printf "[%s]\n" "${a[@]}"
[1 2]
[3 4]
```

Then if you want to copy it to another array, just treat it like an array instead of a string.

```
b=( "${a[@]}" )
printf "[%s]\n" "${b[@]}"
[1 2]
[3 4]
```

To *convert* the *string* created in `a="'1 2' '3 4'"` to an array is a little trickier.

***IF*** you *know* that the format is a consistent match for the above, try this:

```
$: echo "[$a]"
['1 2' '3 4']
$: IFS='#' read -ra b < <( sed -E "s/' +'/#/g; s/ *' *//g" <<< "$a" )
$: printf "[%s]\n" "${b[@]}"
[1 2]
[3 4]
```

but generally, this is a bad plan. Try to fix your *input*!

Comment: I means I have a string variable `a="'1 2' '3 4'"`, and how could I translate it to a array? THX.

Comment: That's a little harder. How consistent is that format?

Comment: We already have existing knowledge base entries that do what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @PaulHodges THX, the pattern is consistent with mine, it can solve my problem, THX.